# Install two instances of a Windows desktop application on the same computer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have written a application using VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

My client wants to be able to have two instances of the application installed on the same computer. One would be the production version and the other a test version. They would be connected to two different databases.

Of course when I try to install the second instance I get the message "You cannot start application 'MyApp' from this location because it is already installed from a different location."

I have tried to copy the project to a new folder, change the connection string and publish it from there but I still get the same error message.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Per  paqogomez This application is a Click Once app.

paqogomez's second comment led be to a site with the answer:

http://www.helplessautomation.com/2011/02/clickonce-deployment-deploying-multiple-versions-of-the-same-application/

Thanks paqogomez!!!

Comment: Is this a click once application? [if so, reading this will help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8c62342e-1382-46ae-8ed3-f2d0c2f907ac/clickonce-you-cannot-start-application-from-this-location-because-it-is-already-installed-from-a)

Comment: This is an interesting topic.  Still, there is [a lot of stuff about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5430669/2589202) on SO.

Comment: paqogomez - Yes this is a click once application.

Comment: or how about they just change the config setting to point to another database they want to test against? not that difficult....

Comment: Just changing the connection string in the config file will not allow for installing two instances of the program on the same computer. The client would have to uninstall one version to install the next.

Comment: or double click a .bat file that swaps the config and then boots up the application. As far as they know it would be 2 instances installed.

Comment: paqogomez led me to a site that gave me the answer: http://www.helplessautomation.com/2011/02/clickonce-deployment-deploying-multiple-versions-of-the-same-application/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing a Click Once Application from two different locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316882/installing-a-click-once-application-from-two-different-locations)

Comment: CodeCaster - your link took me to the same page as paqogomez's second Comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to install 'two versions' of the same ClickOnce application:

On the project's Property page select the Application tab and change the Assembly name;

On the project's Property page select the Publish tab, click the Options button under the Install Mode and Settings and change the Product name (so you can distinguish between the two when installed).

If you need to connect to different databases and you have the setting for the connection string you can change that by:

On the project's Property page select the Settings tab and changing the Value.

If you have any trouble follow this link:

http://www.helplessautomation.com/2011/02/clickonce-deployment-deploying-multiple-versions-of-the-same-application/

Thanks to paqogomez for pointing me in the right direction.